# How to get the search box value in <p> tag - HTML,JS

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, search-box

Am new to javascript i foud this one in [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com) -  **Entering pincode in search box will show in `<p>` tag** !! How to do ? any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

**HTML :**

```
<form class="form1" role="search" method="get" action="search-pincode.html">
<input class="pincode1" type="number" placeholder="Enter Postcode" id="user-pincode">
<button class="submit" type="submit" formaction="search-pincode.html" onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
</form>
```

**JS SCRIPT :**

```
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("user-pincode").value;
    document.getElementById("user-pincode-show").innerHTML = x;
    }
    </script>
```

**OUTPUT : search-pincode.html**

```
                <h1 class="search-h1-contact">
                Yes, we install CCTV in <p id="user-pincode-show"></p>
                </h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one, you will not see the result long enough because after clicking the button, you are being redirected to `search-pincode.html`. Try changing `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("user-pincode").value;
  document.getElementById("user-pincode-show").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<form class="form1" role="search" method="get" action="search-pincode.html">
  <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Postcode" id="user-pincode">
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
</form>

<h1 class="search-h1-contact">
  Yes, we install CCTV in
  <p id="user-pincode-show"></p>
</h1>
```

If what you are planning is to pass the value of the input to `search-pincode.html`, and `user-pincode-show` is inside it, then using JavaScript is not proper way to do it

Comment: Great ! It works. Can you suggest me which way better to pass the value ?

Comment: Well, if it just passing in the same page, this is enough, or use Jquery for a shorter version, but still the same function

Comment: Yes, using search-box in every page now again trying to pass the value from index page.Its not working :'( well moving to jquery

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid redirecting on form submition you can declare an event listener using [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to handle the click event and call `e.preventDefault` in the function handler..

Also notice that there is no need to add `formaction="search-pincode.html"` in the `button` element because the `form` has the attribute `action="search-pincode.html"`

And last thing: With in the `h1` element you can better use a `span` element instead of `p`.

```
<h1>Yes, we install CCTV in <span id="user-pincode-show"></span></h1>
```

Code example:

```js
document
  .querySelector('button.submit')
  .addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = document.querySelector('#user-pincode');
    document.querySelector('#user-pincode-show').innerHTML = x.value;
  });
```

```html
<form class="form1" role="search" method="get" action="search-pincode.html">
  <input class="pincode1" type="number" placeholder="Enter Postcode" id="user-pincode">
  <button class="submit" type="submit">Check</button>
</form>

<h1>Yes, we install CCTV in <span id="user-pincode-show"></span></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("user-pincode");
document.getElementById('user-pincode-show').innerHTML = x.value;
    }
```

```html
<form class="form1" role="search" method="get" action="search-pincode.html">
  <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Postcode" id="user-pincode">
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
</form>

<h1 class="search-h1-contact">
                Yes, we install CCTV in
<p id="user-pincode-show"></p></h1>
```